# Sorting by columns after grouping generating error

Tags: python, pandas

Could anyone please tell me why sorting is generating an error here? I suspect it is related to indexing but reset_index didnt solve the issue

```
df['s'] = df.groupby(['ID','Date'],as_index=False)['Text_Data']\
                   .transform(lambda x :  ' '.join(x))\
                   .sort_values(['ID','Date']) .
```

> KeyError: ('ID', 'Date')

What I was trying to do is to sort the dataframe regardless grouping. In R you would do `ungroup()` first not sure anything simliar is necessary in Pyhton? Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @user4394147 Please provide the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['ID','Date'],as_index=False)['Text_Data'].transform(lambda x :  ' '.join(x))
```

This above code will give you a `Pandas Series` which consists of only one column `Text_Data`. But when you apply `sort_values(['ID','Date'])`, this generates an error because there are no `ID` and `Date` Columns present here.

You can separately sort your dataframe and transformed your column into Series. Then, delete that column from dataframe and append the transformed column to it like this,

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])
df['s'] = df.groupby(['ID','Date'],as_index=False)['Text_Data'].transform(lambda x :  ' '.join(x))
del df['Text_Data']
df['Text_Data] = df['s'].values
```

Comment: @user4394147 let me know if this worked for you. And If some problem occurs, let me know that and I would try to resolve that soon!